# Process records in the file based on arrival timestamp using Java 8 filters, lambda experssions

Tags: data-structures, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a csv with has two columns

```
    Date                Client
1)  4/22/2018 9:00      XYZ
2)  4/22/2018 9:00      ABC
3)  4/22/2018 9:00      LMN
4)  4/22/2018 9:00      ABC
5)  4/22/2018 9:00      ABC  
6)  4/22/2018 9:00      ABC
7)  4/22/2018 9:01      ABC
8)  4/22/2018 9:02      ABC
```

In a minute only 2 records can be processed for a client and rest should be discarded. For example , for ABC clint row # 2,4  will be processed. row #5 and 6 will be discarded. Row 7 , 8 would be processed too for ABC. Similarly, for other clients only 2 records can be processed within a min. The final result will only contain only 6 rows. How can I achieve this using Java 8 filter/lambda expression. I am thinking to sort it first or save timestamp of first trade for a client. I am not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a container class for the `Date` and `Client`, overriding `equals` and `hashcode` as follows:

```
class Wrapper {
   private LocalDateTime dateTime;
   private String client;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Wrapper wrapper = (Wrapper) o;

        return (dateTime != null ? dateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
                .equals(wrapper.dateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)) :
                wrapper.dateTime == null) && (client != null ?
                client.equals(wrapper.client) : wrapper.client == null);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = dateTime != null ?
                dateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (client != null ? client.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Wrapper{" +
                "dateTime=" + dateTime +
                ", client='" + client + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public Wrapper(LocalDateTime dateTime, String client) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.client = client;
    }
}
```

Then as you're reading the file, spin up however many objects required populating it with the necessary data.

Now, you can accomplish the task at hand with:

```
List<Wrapper> resultSet = myList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.toList()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().limit(2))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

at a high-level explanation this groups the `Wrapper` objects by the `date` (excluding seconds*) and `client` retaining two objects maximum per group hence satisfying your description of "In a minute only 2 records can be processed for a client and rest should be discarded".

at a low-level explanation:

1. `myList.stream()` creates a stream object from the source list, therefore, enabling us to build a pipeline of operations.
2. `collect` accepts a `Collector` which groups the objects in the source list by `date` (excluding seconds*) and `client` ( this is the current implementation of the `equals` method).
3. [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) takes a function extracting the "thing" to group by in this case that is  `Function.identity()` meaning the `Wrapper` objects.
4. `LinkedHashMap::new` is a supplier providing a new empty map into which the results will be inserted (a `LinkedHashMap` specifically to maintain insertion order).
5. `Collectors.toList()` is the downstream collector, enabling us to collect all the `Wrapper` objects in the same bucket in a `List<T>` instance.
6. `.entrySet().stream()` creates a `Stream<Map.Entry<Wrapper, List<Wrapper>>>` from the `Map<Wrapper, List<Wrapper>>` after the `groupingBy` operation.
7. `.flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().limit(2))` performs a mapping function to take a maximum of `2` elements in each list and flattens it into a `Stream<Wrapper>`.
8. `.collect(Collectors.toList())` collects the `Wrapper` objects of the `Stream<Wrapper>` to a list implementation.

For demonstration puporses assume our list contains the following objects:

```
List<Wrapper> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                        new Wrapper(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 2, 22, 9, 0), "XYZ"),
                        new Wrapper(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 2, 22, 9, 0), "ABC"),
                        new Wrapper(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 2, 22, 9, 0), "LMN"),
                        new Wrapper(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 2, 22, 9, 0), "ABC"),
                        new Wrapper(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 2, 22, 9, 0), "ABC"),
                        new Wrapper(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 2, 22, 9, 0), "ABC"),
                        new Wrapper(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 2, 22, 9, 1), "ABC"),
                        new Wrapper(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 2, 22, 9, 2), "ABC")    
                ));
```

After running the above stream pipeline the result is:

```
[Wrapper{dateTime=2018-02-22T09:00, client='XYZ'}, 
 Wrapper{dateTime=2018-02-22T09:00, client='ABC'}, 
 Wrapper{dateTime=2018-02-22T09:00, client='ABC'}, 
 Wrapper{dateTime=2018-02-22T09:00, client='LMN'}, 
 Wrapper{dateTime=2018-02-22T09:01, client='ABC'}, 
 Wrapper{dateTime=2018-02-22T09:02, client='ABC'}]
```

Note - I've named this class `Wrapper` simply because I don't know your domain model, I will leave it to you upon deciding a more appropriate and meaningful name.

Comment: note that I've collected the elements to a `List<T>` instance but if you want to apply an action on each element instead then you can replace `.collect(Collectors.toList());` with `.forEach(e -> action(e))` where `action` is the method processing the elements.

Comment: Hi Aomine - it worked that..but I am not able to understand what do following lines of code do                                                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                          LinkedHashMap::new,
                          Collectors.toList()))
                  .entrySet()
                  .stream()

Comment: @question_tech I don't think the explanation will fit in a comment, I will update my answer shortly and explain everything in detail.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will be waiting for your response.

Comment: @question_tech I've provided more explanation to clarify what the code does.